# CSS control rotation based on class name

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have things on a map that I want to rotate a varying number of degrees. I'm using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/index.html) for the map. I'm using a [marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker) with a customer icon. The icon is the thing that I want to rotate.

I can't seem to target the icon with javascript but I do have control over it's `className` so I was wondering, could I use something like `r90` or any other number to rotate the icon 90 degrees without having to write like 360 style rules?

Something like

```
.r1 { transform: rotate(1deg) }
...
.r90 { transform: rotate(90deg) }
.r91 { transform: rotate(91deg) }
.r92 { transform: rotate(92deg) }
...
.r359 { transform: rotate(359deg) }
```

and turn it into

```
[class$=deg] {
  transform: rotate(attr(class));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not averse to adding SCSS to your workflow, you can do something like

```css
@for $deg from 1 through 359 {
    .r{$deg} {
        transform: rotate({$deg}deg);
    }
}
```

And then the SCSS preprocessor will write your 359 classes for you

That said, I'm not 100% sure whether it'll work in leaflet or not (due to not knowing how leaflet works, see comment by Roko C. Buljan)

Comment: [It worked](https://i.imgur.com/mSZdRPf.png). I'm targeting an `::after` pseudo element, something leaflet doesn't style. I'll just live with a big repetitive css file. It's fine.